# Windows 2008 and Truecrypt: can't access shared folder called "media"

Tags: windows-server-2008, network-share

On my Windows 2008 system, I've attached an external USB drive that's encrypted using Truecrypt. Once I mounted the Truecrypt drive, I share some of the directories from that drive using Windows file sharing.  I tried sharing a folder called "media" and when I try to access that folder from a Vista client on my LAN via \myserver\media, I get this error:

> \myserver\media is not accessible.
>   You might not have permission to use
>   this network resource. Contact the
>   administrator of this server to find
>   out if you have access permissions.
>
> An unexpected network error occurred.

If I share the folder media under some name such as fizzbuzz then I can access \myserver\fizzbuzz w/o any errors.

Any clues as to why this is happening?

Related:
[Windows 2008 and Truecrypt: how to automatically mount shared folders after restart?](https://serverfault.com/questions/27684/windows-2008-and-truecrypt-how-to-automatically-mount-shared-folders-after-rest)

Comment: Sometimes the Event Log (eventvwr.msc) gives useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Media might just be a reserved share name?

Try checking fsmgmt.msc and look for anything similarly named.

Also, instead of Server 2008 - Windows Home Server would be MUCH better suited for your use!

Comment: I check fsmgmt and it doesn't appear that "media" is reserved.  Perhaps this is some Truecrypt/Windows file sharing oddity.

I considered WHS but I went with Windows 2008 b/c I'm using Vista at home and I wanted to take advantage of the SMB2 speed improvements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess "media" is reserved for some Plug-N-Play style magic Windows itself might use for media sharing/playback; like IPC$ is for other uses.